# Как написать модель json ответа

Tags: java, android, json

```
{"data": [[1, "code party", "\u041f\u0430\u0442\u0438 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0447\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0438\u0445 \u043a\u043e\u0434\u0435\u0440\u043e\u0432", "123;432;234;464", 56.99559, 58.6666, 24293930, 1, 160, "[6]"], [2, "code party", "\u041f\u0430\u0442\u0438 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0447\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0438\u0445 \u043a\u043e\u0434\u0435\u0440\u043e\u0432", "123;432;234;464", 56.99559, 58.6666, 25302436, 1, 160, "[6]"], [3, "code party", "\u041f\u0430\u0442\u0438 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0447\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0438\u0445 \u043a\u043e\u0434\u0435\u0440\u043e\u0432", "123;432;234;464", 56.99559, 58.6666, 43560601, 1, 160, "[6]"], [4, "code party", "\u041f\u0430\u0442\u0438 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0447\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0438\u0445 \u043a\u043e\u0434\u0435\u0440\u043e\u0432", "123", 56.99559, 58.6666, 16398657, 1, 160, "[6]"], [5, "code party hard", "\u041f\u0430\u0442\u0438 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0447\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0438\u0445 \u043a\u043e\u0434\u0435\u0440\u043e\u0432", "123", 56.99559, 58.6666, 90516142, 1, 160, "[6]"], [6, "code party hard", "\u041f\u0430\u0442\u0438 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0447\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0438\u0445 \u043a\u043e\u0434\u0435\u0440\u043e\u0432", "123", 56.99559, 58.6666, 87319277, 1, 160, "[6]"], [7, "hxhhzhd", "bxhzhhxh", null, 20.492508333333333, 54.73706333333333, 86049180, 1, 9565659, "[6]"], [8, "rhfh", "fhdh", null, 20.4925083333, 54.7370633333, 88940018, 1, 56, "[6]"], [9, "\u0431\u0435\u0437\u0443\u043c\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0445\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0442\u043e\u043d \u0431\u043e\u0440\u0449", "\u0442\u0443\u0441\u0438\u043c \u0445\u0430\u0442\u0430 \u043d\u0433", null, 20.4925083333, 54.7370633333, 60642689, 1, 600, "[6]"], [10, "123", "321", null, 20.4925083333, 54.7370633333, 96693563, 1, 50, "[6]"], [11, "k\u00f6nighack", "it project", null, 20.4925083333, 54.7370633333, 44457300, 1, 1000, "[6]"], [12, "\u043c\u0435\u0439\u043a\u0435\u0440", "\u043a\u0435\u043a", null, 20.4925083333, 54.7370633333, 98841109, 1, 10, "[6]"], [13, "\u0427\u0430\u0439\u0442\u0442", "\u0447\u0430\u0439 \u0438 \u0442\u0434", null, 20.492508333333333, 54.73706333333333, 20826308, 1, 50, "[6]"], [14, "\u0442\u0443\u0441\u0430 \u0441 \u043a\u0435\u0448\u0435\u0439", "...", null, 20.4925083333, 54.7370633333, 43607356, 1, 55, "[6]"], [15, "\u0443\u0440\u043e\u043a ", "\u0448\u043f\u0438\u043e\u0438\u043c \u0438\u043d\u0433\u043b\u0438\u0448", null, 20.4925083333, 54.7370633333, 21409752, 1, 23, "[6]"], [16, "\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0442", "\u043f\u043e\u0438\u0433\u043e", null, 20.4925083333, 54.7370633333, 24775979, 1, 200000, "[6]"], [17, "\u041a\u0440\u0443\u0442\u0430\u044f", "\u0432\u0430\u043f\u0440\u043e\u043e\u043e\u043e", null, 20.527556666666666, 54.72485833333334, 77317282, 1, 500, "[6]"], [18, "\u0411\u0444\u0443 \u0422\u0443\u0441\u0430", "\u0422\u0443\u0441\u0430 \u0432 \u0431\u0444\u0443", null, 20.527228333333333, 54.72480833333334, 85404755, 1, 5000, "[6]"], [19, "\u0442\u0440\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u043a\u0438", "\u043a\u0430\u0447\u0430\u0435\u0430", null, 20.4925083333, 54.7370633333, 51300968, 1, 10, "[6]"], [20, "\u0435\u0430\u0432", "\u0430\u0430\u0432", null, 20.4925083333, 54.7370633333, 85214314, 1, 10, "[6]"], [21, "tuff", "fhij", null, 20.4925083333, 54.7370633333, 49247285, 1, 10, "[6]"], [22, "\u0431\u0444\u0443 \u0445\u0430\u0440\u0434 \u043f\u0430\u0442\u0438 \u043d\u0430 \u043d\u0438\u0436\u043a\u0435", "\u0442\u0443\u0441\u0441\u0441\u044d\u044d", null, 20.5125464, 54.724913, 36083020, 1, 8000, "[6]"], [23, "\u0443\u0440\u043e\u043a", "\u043f\u0438\u0432\u043e\u043a", null, 20.5216508, 54.7078369, 21829778, 1, 28, "[6]"], [24, "\u0435\u0435 \u0440\u043e\u043a\u043a", "\u0436\u043e\u043f\u0430", null, 20.5216508, 54.7078369, 12008101, 1, 22, "[6]"], [25, null, null, null, 20.52115, 54.752811666666666, 94927673, 1, 5, "[6]"], [26, "\u044d\u043f\u0438\u043a \u043f\u0430\u0442\u0438", "\u043f\u0430\u0442\u0438 \u043d\u0430 \u043d\u0438\u0436\u043a\u0435", null, 20.5279077, 54.7249087, 85310651, 1, 500, "[6]"], [27, null, null, null, 20.499078333333333, 54.72215500000001, 25162452, 1, 5, "[6]"], [28, "qwerty", "qwert", null, 20.499675, 54.72225666666667, 40467921, 1, 2, "[6]"], [29, "\u043f\u043f\u043f", "\u043c\u043e\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0443", null, 20.4925083333, 54.7370633333, 44776171, 1, 10, "[6]"], [30, "\u0430\u043e\u043c\u0438", "\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0441", null, 20.502145, 54.71833333333334, 38406890, 1, 55, "[6]"], [31, "\u044c\u043f\u043b\u0430\u043b", "\u043b\u0430\u043b\u043b\u0430", null, 20.524036666666667, 54.72180166666667, 86931652, 1, 656, "[6]"]], "code": 200, "msg": "Success"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такой [ресурс](http://jsonutils.com/)

Судя по нему, ваша модель будет выглядеть как

```
public class Example
{
    private List<List<Object>> data;
    private int code;
    private String msg;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public List<List<Object>> getData() { 
         return this.data 
    }

    public List<List<Object>> setData(List<List<Object>> data) { 
         this.data = data 
    }

    @JsonProperty("code")
    public int getCode() { 
         return this.code 
    }

    public int setCode(int code) { 
         this.code = code 
    }

    @JsonProperty("msg")
    public String getMsg() { 
         return this.msg 
    }

    public String setMsg(String msg) { 
         this.msg = msg 
    }
}
```

Можно также воспользоватся [таким ресурсом](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Тогда модель будет выглядеть вот так

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"data",
"code",
"msg"
})
public class Example {

@JsonProperty("data")
private List<List<Integer>> data = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
@JsonProperty("code")
private Integer code;
@JsonProperty("msg")
private String msg;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
*
* @return
* The data
*/
@JsonProperty("data")
public List<List<Integer>> getData() {
return data;
}

/**
*
* @param data
* The data
*/
@JsonProperty("data")
public void setData(List<List<Integer>> data) {
this.data = data;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The code
*/
@JsonProperty("code")
public Integer getCode() {
return code;
}

/**
*
* @param code
* The code
*/
@JsonProperty("code")
public void setCode(Integer code) {
this.code = code;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The msg
*/
@JsonProperty("msg")
public String getMsg() {
return msg;
}

/**
*
* @param msg
* The msg
*/
@JsonProperty("msg")
public void setMsg(String msg) {
this.msg = msg;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

Comment: Как работать с этим 
    private List<List<Object>> data;

Comment: У вас по факту список массивов в элементе `data`. Что не так?

Comment: отличный ресурс и ответ